# Pinned ParseObject does not have createdAt or updatedAt field values

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am pinning a parseobject to the local data store, as soon as I create it. When I retrieve the parseobject that I pinned with the below code, in my android activity, I am able to pull all the records, but I am not able to retrieve the createdAt and updatedAt fields for any of the objects. What do I do to retrieve them?

If parse doesn't assign those values to pinned in local datastore parseobjects, is there a way I can attach a custom updatedAt field that takes care of the timestamp updating by itself?

```
ParseQuery<PostChoice> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PostChoice");
                                    query.fromPin("collegeUserChoice");

                                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<PostChoice>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(List<PostChoice> list, ParseException e) {
                                            for(PostChoice pc:list)
                                            {
                                                Log.i("updatedAt" , pc.getCreatedAt().toString() /*(pc.getCreatedAt()).toString()*/);
                                           // **this line throws java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Date.toString()' on a null object reference**                                                
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Date.toString()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this post is dated, but I came here looking to solve the same problem.

This works with data fetched from parse:

```
created_at =  Message.getDate("createdAt");
```

This call will not work with data fetched from local data storage. The code below will, however, work with both data from parse and local data storage:

```
created_at = Message.getCreatedAt();
```

One I gotcha is that local data storage needs to be set up in the initialization call instead of prior with the most recent library.